# What is the proper ettiquette if I have a clarification too long for a comment?

Tags: discussion

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18495471/adding-rows-to-datagrid-through-xaml) earlier. The accepted answer is correct and led me immediately to the proper solution, but the code provided is incomplete and will not produce the desired results without a few additional lines. The formatting (or even necessity) of those lies may be non-obvious to a WPF newbie and one other commenter on the original answer had already been tripped up by the omitted info.

My initial inclination would be to provide this sort of info via a comment on the original answer, but I couldn't think of a way to describe it understandably without providing a few lines of example code and that doesn't lend itself well to a comment.

I ended up adding a partial answer with a note to the original poster suggesting they incorporate my example into their own answer, but I'm not sure if this was the correct approach.

What's the best etiquette for a situation like this? Should I post an edit suggestion to the original answer? Should I post a complete answer that incorporates the existing answer but expands upon it? Is a partial answer like I gave ok?

Comment: Post another answer, post a link to the original answer and the author's profile.

Comment: Your approach sound reasonable. Note: don't use "accepted answer" or "answer above/below" as these are relative and can change any time. Instead grab link to answer from "share" button and construct link like "[ according to answer ]( link_from_share )" or just "link_from_share" if it reads ok in your post.